# Why there is no need to change Certificate pinned in android app even after Renewing SSL Certifcate?

Tags: android, ssl, ssl-certificate, certificate-pinning

I am using SSL `Certificate Pining` in my android app, now when I renewed the SSL Certificate then I thought as I am only doing `Certificate Pining` not `Public Key Pining` in my Android App I will need to change Certificate in my android project and again update my app on the play store, but the thing is my app is working completely fine without the need to update Certificate file in my Android Project.

Can anyone please tell me is this the normal behaviour ??

**Code**

```
public Certificate findCertificate() throws CertificateException {
        CertificateFactory instance = CertificateFactory.getInstance("X.509");
        InputStream resourceAsStream = getResources().openRawResource(R.folder.certificate_name);
        InputStream bufferedInputStream = new BufferedInputStream(resourceAsStream);
        try {
            Certificate generateCertificate = instance.generateCertificate(bufferedInputStream);
            try {
                resourceAsStream.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
            }
            return generateCertificate;
        } finally {
            try {
                bufferedInputStream.close();
            } catch (IOException e2) {
            }
            try {
                resourceAsStream.close();
            } catch (IOException e3) {
            }
        }
    }

    public SSLContext findSSLConfiguration(Context context) throws CertificateException, IOException,
            KeyStoreException, NoSuchAlgorithmException, KeyManagementException {

        CertificateFactory cf = null;
        cf = CertificateFactory.getInstance("X.509");

        Certificate ca = findCertificate();

        String keyStoreType = KeyStore.getDefaultType();
        KeyStore keyStore = KeyStore.getInstance(keyStoreType);
        keyStore.load(null, null);
        keyStore.setCertificateEntry("ca", ca);

        String tmfAlgorithm = TrustManagerFactory.getDefaultAlgorithm();
        TrustManagerFactory tmf = TrustManagerFactory.getInstance(tmfAlgorithm);
        tmf.init(keyStore);

        SSLContext sslContext = SSLContext.getInstance("TLS");
        sslContext.init(null, tmf.getTrustManagers(), null);

        return sslContext;
    }

    public void server_call() throws CertificateException, NoSuchAlgorithmException, KeyStoreException, KeyManagementException, IOException {
        OkHttpClient okHttp = new OkHttpClient.Builder()
                .sslSocketFactory(findSSLConfiguration(getBaseContext()).getSocketFactory())
                .build();
    }
```

Comment: Show us your code.

Comment: @SLaks Please see my updated code.

Comment: Are you sure this code does certificate pinning against the **server certificate**? Given the names you use I would rather assume that **"ca"** is the certificate authority (the issuer of the certificate, which did not change when renewing) and not the server certificate. What is the certificate you are actually loading in your code?

Comment: @SteffenUllrich Certificate which is inside `folder.certificate_name`belongs to `myorganization`, not the issuer's certificate.

Comment: @SudhanshuGaur: *"belongs to myorganization"* does not clearly sound like a server certificate. So is this the **leaf** certificate the server will send or not or is it some CA certificate or what?

Comment: @SteffenUllrich I have tried both certificates that is `mydomain.com`  as well as a concatenated certificate of both `ca's` and `mydomain.com`. But for both app is working fine.

Comment: @SteffenUllrich But in android code certificate I have added is only of `mydomain.com`, So as it got changed why app is working completely fine ??

Comment: @SteffenUllrich are you there ??

Comment: @SudhanshuGaur: I'm here but I cannot help anymore. There is no way for me to reproduce what is really going on.